# Play streamed audio chunks via Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, browser, web-audio-api

Since `AudioContext.decodeAudioData()` does not support streaming, what are my options for playing streamed audio chunks? Are their any libraries that I can use? Any resources that you might be able to point me to?

Comment: Streaming from what?

Comment: @brad I’m streaming an audio file from a server to a client via socket.io

Comment: What is the audio file?  What codec?  Why are you using Socket.IO?  Why not just use HTTP and let the `<audio>` element take care of it?

Comment: Based on what I've seen, the audio tag waits for the file to download before it starts to play. I don't want that. It's an .mp3 file. Socket.io allows me to send the file in chunks.

Comment: No, that isn't true.  The `<audio>` tag can be used for streaming just fine, and is done so regularly for pretty much every internet radio site there is.  There is also MediaSource Extensions for more advanced needs, but it has more codec and container limitations.

Comment: I have tried it and it had to download the file before it could play it. Could you maybe show me an example?

Comment: It really is as simple as `<audio src="https://example.com/stream"></audio>`.  I usually add `preload="none"` as an attribute to prevent any loading until the user clicks play, but I assure you that it does support live streaming.  In fact, I don't know of *any* browser that downloads the whole "file" before playing back.  I've never seen that behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217998/discussion-between-dowen-robinson-and-brad).